# continuous function question

Tags: propositional-calculus

Assume that function $f$ is continuous at $x=0$. Prove that the function 
$f(x)=a^x$
for $a>0 $, is continuous at every real number.

I know that $f$ is continuous at 0 if and only if 0 is in the domain of $f$ and $lim_(h→0)⁡〖{f(0+h)-f(0) ]=0〗$. But how can I use this to prove this problem?

Comment: If you "assume that this function $f$ is continuous at $0$", then you can use the fact that $f(x+h)=f(x)f(h)$ (with $h$ sufficiently small) to prove that $f$ is continuous at $x$, for all $x>0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wants you to *assume* that it's continuous at $x=0$, and use that to prove that it's continuous everywhere else. In particular, you're assuming that $$\lim_{x\to 0}|a^x-1|=0.\tag{$\clubsuit$}$$ Now, note that for any $x_0$, we can write $$|a^x-a^{x_0}|=|a^{x_0}||a^{x-x_0}-1|.\tag{$\heartsuit$}$$ Using $(\clubsuit)$ and $(\heartsuit)$ together with the fact that $|a^{x_0}|>0$ for all $x_0$, we can prove continuity anywhere else with an $\epsilon$-$\delta$ style approach.